# How to create bayesian test for ROI/ROAS metric

Tags: probability, bayesian, marketing

I am interested in using A/B Bayesian testing to compare [ROAS](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/finance/roas-return-on-ad-spend/) for marketing scenarios.

I've seen [references](https://www.evanmiller.org/bayesian-ab-testing.html) dealing with cases such as:

- Using a beta distribution prior to model a binomial-distributed random variable;
- Using a gamma distribution prior to model a Poisson-distributed random variable.

In my case, knowing that $\text{ROAS} = \text{Revenue}/\text{Cost}$, is there any convenient prior in the Bayesian context?

In other words, in a situation where I have the cost and revenue data for two scenarios A and B, how can I use Bayesian Testing to calculate the probability that $\text{ROAS}_A > \text{ROAS}_B$?

The distribution of revenue for each conversion (success event) is not necessarily known, but I accept modeling suggestions to simplify the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem in my company [MarkTech](http://marktech.tech/).
I'm waiting for an update on this question since last year.